# what is the difference between ".next" and ".next()" in java?

Tags: java

When I want to find the next element in a set, which one should I use? ".next" or ".next()", are they same?

```
public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
    Set<ListNode> nodesInB = new HashSet<ListNode>();

    while (headB != null) {
        nodesInB.add(headB);
        headB = headB.next;
    }
}
```

in the code above, it uses ".next", can I use ".next()" ??

Comment: What type is `headB` of?

Comment: its type is ListNode

Comment: And `ListNode` is?

Comment: .next is an instance variable, and .next() is a method. They are not the same.

Comment: can I use" .next" directly in Java?

Comment: The reason you might use .next() would be as a typical getter method in the case that your `ListNode next` variable is private

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know your `ListNode` class, and you neglected to link to its documentation, I can explain the syntax. If you want a more specific answer, you should edit the Question to include vital details.

## Method call versus Member field

- `x.next()` calls an [accessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) named `next` on the [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) [referenced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) by the variable named `x`.
- `x.next` accesses a [member field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable) held by the object referenced by the variable named `x`.

They may or may not have the same effect. You did not supply enough information for us to discern.

### Access a `record` via method call versus member field

I can show an example where both member field and a getter method access the same object. This is the way the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature works in Java 16.

A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You simply define the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, the getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

So this is my invented version of your undescribed `ListNode` class:

```
public record ListNode( String next ) { }  // A class carrying a single member field named `next` of type `String`.
```

Let's instantiate one.

```
ListNode ln = new ListNode( "Cockatiel" ) ;
```

Call `toString` to see its contents.

```
String output = ln.toString();
```

> ListNode[next=Cockatiel]

The `next` field is actually `private` so it cannot be accessed outside this class. But let's say we want to replace the default `toString` method otherwise generated by compiler. We could do so by either calling the getter method, or by accessing the member field. So both of the following implementations have the same effect.

#### Member field access

```java
public record ListNode(String next)
{
    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "This `ListNode` object has a value of " + this.next ;
    }
}
```

> This `ListNode` object has a value of Cockatiel

#### Getter method call

Put some parentheses on the end to make a method call rather than access a member field.

```java
public record ListNode(String next)
{
    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "This `ListNode` object has a value of " + this.next() ;
    }
}
```

> This `ListNode` object has a value of Cockatiel